# jQuery ajax dialog keeps sending same values

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, smarty

It seems i'm having a problem with a jQuery ajax form, it keeps sending the same value although the form fields appear to be empty. Therefore i assume jQuery is "caching" or not overwriting the vars i defined.

```
function payment(projectID, billID)
{
    $.ajax
    ({
        url: 'modules/projects/projectFinancial.php?action=paymentDetails&projectID=' + projectID + '&billID=' + billID + '&rand=' + Math.random(),
        dataType: 'html',
        async: false,
        success: function(msg)
        {
            $("#paymentDetails").html(msg);
        }
    });

    $("#payment").dialog(
    {
        width: 500,
        height: 300,
        modal: true,
        buttons: 
        {
            Save: function()
            {
                var paymentAmount = $("#PaymentAmount").val();
                var paymentMethod = $("#PaymentMethod").val();
                var paymentRemarks = $("#PaymentRemarks").val();

                if ($('#PaymentDone').is(':checked'))
                {
                    var paymentDone = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    var paymentDone = 0;
                }

                $.ajax
                ({
                    url: 'modules/projects/projectFinancial.php?action=payment&projectID=' + projectID + '&billID=' + billID + '&paymentAmount=' + paymentAmount + '&paymentMethod=' + paymentMethod + '&paymentRemarks=' + paymentRemarks + '&paymentDone=' + paymentDone + '&rand=' + Math.random(),
                    dataType: 'html',
                    async: false,
                    success: function(msg)
                    {
                        if (msg != "error")
                        {
                            showFinancial(msg, '{/literal}{$marginCalculated}{literal}');
                        }
                    }
                });

                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off caching entirely using the code below. Also, you should use **POST** method for actions that alter something on the server (*payment* seems such an action).

```
$(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});
```

**Another thought:** make sure that upon clicking Save for the second time, `#PaymentAmount` refers to the input field in the *second* dialog box. Using IDs in dynamically-loaded content is risky because you can easily end up with duplicate IDs if you load the same thing more than once.

`$(this).dialog("close")` doesn't actually remove the old dialog from the DOM.
Try using `$(this).dialog("destroy")` instead.

Comment: Oops, it appears the op has already implemented that manually. See `'&rand=' + Math.random()` at the end of the URL.

Comment: Declare your variable in the begining of the function and later change its value without declaration ( var paymentDone = 0; in the if/else ). If you checking in/out the #PaymentDone you may redeclare your variable

Comment: Well. i tried the cache: false suggestion, which does not seem to have any effect. I also changed the dialog close to destroy, and the change this makes is that upon re-opening the dialog it actually shows the values i entered the previous time, something it didn't do with dialog.close.

I also tried to set all values to '', this indeed empties the input fields, but when submitting it submits empty vars, while i fetch the values upon pressing the save button.

Comment: If you `console.log` the URL that does into the ajax call, does it contain the correct values?

Comment: It does not unfortunally. If for instance i enter the following values: Amount 25 / Remark: test 1 and save it than it is entered in the database correctly. Than i re-open te dialog to insert another payment and the same values are still inside the input fields. The strange thing than is, when i alter those values and press save, it outputs empty.

Comment: P.S. one thing worth mentioning, the actual input fields are loaded into the dialog's div using ajax. I reload that form everytime i hit save so it's really weird it saves the content of those fields.

Comment: Use the Firebug or Chrome DevTools console to find the element that `$("#PaymentAmount")` selects. Is it the one that is visible and appears on the current dialog? Or better yet, use a class, or use scoping to limit the jQuery selector to the current instance of the dialog.

Comment: When i view that element with firebug it shows the value to be empty, still the input field contains 25 as amount.

Comment: Then it's not the same element. Change the ID to a class and test in Firebug whether you have multiple elements with that class after reopening the dialog.